# What Determines the Default Setting of the x87 FPU Control Word?

Tags: visual-c++, floating-point, rounding, floating-accuracy, fpu

What determines the default setting of the x87 FPU control word -- specifically, the precision control field? Does the compiler set it based on the target processor? Is there a compiler option to change it?

Using Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Express Edition on an Intel Core Duo processor, the default setting for the precision control field is "01b", meaning double (53 bit) precision. I'm wondering -- why is the default not "11"b, or extended (64 bit) precision?

(I know I can change it using _controlfp.)

Comment: Bruce Dawson's excellent article https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/ has some details about how MSVC messes with the CW setting, usually setting it to 53-bit (so [FLT_EVAL_METHOD](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits/FLT_EVAL_METHOD) == 1 is approximately correct, except for extra exponent range).  But D3D apparently changes it to 24, for somewhat faster div and sqrt, rounding everything to `float`!  Insanity.  Fortunately, even 32-bit code these days can generally assume SSE2 for scalar (and vector) float and double math.

Answer (score 4):

There was a bug in the Microsoft C runtime DLL (MSVCRT.DLL) where it would change the FPCW, which could change application behavior depending on the order of DLL loading.

So if you care about the FPCW setting, it is not only best practice to change it to your desired settings before execution, (even on a function call boundary), but also to change it back when you are done. (And if you call any functions or libaries, beware of callees who might change it and not be so considerate as to change it back for you!)

Also note: the FPCW is expensive to modify, but not very expensive to examine.  So if there's a good chance it is already set the way you want, you can save a lot of time by checking it before modifying it.

Comment: @ArchaeaSW - do you have a KB or MS reference to this bug?  I haven't been able to find anything relevant, and would like to know what version(s) have this bug.

Comment: hmm, I tried to dig it up and was not able to find it. The Web and Microsoft's KB process were still kind of new when that bug was discovered, though.

FPCW still ranks as one of the worst thread-wide pieces of control state in the architecture.  Much of the state in there (esp. round mode) should be encoded on a per-instruction basis.

Comment: The FPCW is "not very expensive to examine". I have been searching around on how to examine the current FPCW value on Windows but didn't reach anything.
Any idea how to do so?

Comment: I'd start with __control87_2() intrinsic, described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/control87-controlfp-control87

Answer (score 0):

From a theoretical standpoint: probably the last thing that used it, or barring that, whatever Intel decided would be a good default.

From a practical standpoint: just set it to your desired precision before you begin work. Explicit defaults are usually better than implied defaults.

Comment: But I'm asking, if I'm the 'first thing that uses it', how did it get set to start with? Why would the default be 53 bit and not 64 bit?

Comment: But you're **not** the first thing that uses it. There's probably BIOS code that's executing.

Comment: That's one thing I'm trying to find out -- where it's initialized.

Comment: Since he's using Visual C++, I bet he is on Windows, which means that MS rather than Intel is responsible for the default since it should be part of the startup configuration for new processes. The BIOS was used really long ago when a Windows process starts.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "first" :)

Answer (score 0):

When the OS sets up a process (or thread) -- say, when your program launches, it is responsible for initializing the control registers to the default state (exactly what the default state is can vary somewhat from platform to platform).  It is also responsible for saving and restoring state around context switches, so that your program doesn't bleed state into some other process that is also running on the system.

Beyond that, a compiler or a language runtime might modify the state before your code is executed.

So either: Windows' default FP state is 53 bit precision or VS2008 inserts code to set the processor to 53 bit precision by default.  The Windows default process state should be documented in the ABI documentation for the platform.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wondering about the same original question. I've experimented with VC++ 6 & MinGW on Windows 2000 (32-bit).

A simple 3-line program had the FPU control word set for 'Double precision' (0x027f) for VC++ and 'Extended precision' when compiled using MinGW (0x037f).
On the same machine, gcc/Linux-32 had the same extended precision (0x37f).
i.e. MinGW and gcc/Linux seems to be having the same FPU setting.